# Which file in Magento is a router of catalog?

Tags: magento, routes, http-status-code-404

Well.
I have several same pages:

```
1) domain/category/subcategory/product-page - THIS is FULL PATH
2) domain/category/product-age
3) domain/product-page
```

I need to set 404 for 2 and 3.
I don`t ask you to solve my problem (but if you know, you are welcome!), but please. What file/class/function I should change?

Answer (score 1):

Router file for product will be

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php
```

you should override this file instead of doing changes in core file.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. I can clean function _initProduct() and my catalog still working.

Comment: instead of copying it on local, you should override ProductController class